# How to validate an editor field in a dojo OnDemandGrid

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo, dgrid

I have built a dojo OnDemandGrid that has a couple columns that have editors (NumberTextBox, and FilteringSelect) so I can modify values in the grid. I have also added some validation on these columns to help make sure the values that are entered are correct. This all appears to be working fine and when I enter an invalid value I get an indication that the value is incorrect.

My problem is when I try to send this data back to the server. When I get the grid data with a ui.searchResultGrid.collection.data, any of the fields that are invalid have not been updated in the collection and still have their original values. My guess is that when the cell is updated and does a save it does its validation, and if that validation fails it doesn't update the collection. How can I tell that some cells have failed validation and have issues?

Here's how I'm defining my grid if it helps:

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid", "dgrid/Keyboard", "dgrid/Selection", "dgrid/Editor", 
        "dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer", "dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry", "dijit/form/NumberTextBox", 
        "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (declare, OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection, Editor, ColumnResizer, DijitRegistry, NumberTextBox, FilteringSelect, lang) {

        var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection, Editor, ColumnResizer, DijitRegistry]);
        ui.searchResultGrid = new CustomGrid({
            columns: {
                newItemAmount: {
                    label: "# of New Item",
                    editor: NumberTextBox,
                    editorArgs: {
                        constraints: {
                            min: 0.0001,
                            max: 999.9999,
                            allowNegative: false,
                            places: 4
                        },
                        style: "width:90px;",
                        required: true
                    },
                    autoSave: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    width: 100
                },
                newItemUnitId: {
                    label: "Unit of New Item",
                    editor: FilteringSelect,
                    editorArgs: {
                        style: "width:130px",
                        searchAttr: "name",
                        labelAttr: "name",
                        required: true
                    },
                    autoSave: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    width: 140
                }
            },
            selectionMode: "none",
            cellNavigation: false,
        }, "searchResultGrid");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to find, you have to look at each cell you want to validate and check .element.widget.isValid() to see if that widget passes validation. I wrote a function to validate a grid with parameters:
grid - the grid to validate
cols - an array of strings of the column names to validate

```
function gridValid(grid, cols) {
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.collection.data.length; i++) {
    var rowId = grid.collection.getIdentity(grid.collection.data[i])
    for (var c = 0; c < cols.length; c++) {
        if (!grid.cell(rowId, cols[c]).element.widget.isValid()) {
        return false;
        }
    };
    }
    return true;
}
```

and I called the function like this:

```
if (gridValid(ui.searchResultGrid, ["newItemAmount", "newItemUnitId"])) {
    var toSave = ui.searchResultGrid.collection.data;
    //TODO: save the grid data
}
```

This may not be the best way to validate the grid, but it appears to be working.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are enough rows such that some are not rendered at validation time, since it is an `OnDemandGrid`. `grid.cell(rowId, cols[c]).element` will be undefined for non-rendered rows.